# Defining TeX count in a group

Tags: counters, grouping

I thought that TeX counts were local definitions, but that is not what I am seeing. I was expecting that if I used `\newcount` within a group, that the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox) `\ifdefcounter` would say that the counter is not defined outside the group. The following code produces:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\ifdefcounter{\mycount}{The counter is defined}{The counter is NOT defined}

\begingroup
\newcount\mycount
\endgroup
\ifdefcounter{\mycount}{The counter is defined}{The counter is NOT defined}
\end{document}
```

> The counter is NOT defined
>
> The counter is defined

Suggesting to me that the counter is not defined at the beginning, but its existence persistence outside the group and hence is not local.

Comment: Local _allocation_ is as the answers indicate quite possible, but as TeX grouping is very different from that in other languages I'd recommend against it. We experimented with local registers in `expl3`, but they were more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to allocate local counters, then you can use `etex.sty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\ifdefcounter{\mycount}{The counter is defined}{The counter is NOT defined}

\begingroup
\loccount\mycount
\advance\mycount 42
\the\mycount

\texttt{\meaning\mycount}
\endgroup

\ifdefcounter{\mycount}{The counter is defined}{The counter is NOT defined}
\end{document}
```

Of course a LaTeX like syntax with `\stepcounter` and so on is out of the question, as these commands are global. One *might* define local versions of them, but I doubt about their usefulness.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Plain and LaTeX  register allocations are global. You should just allocate a few registers globally at the start and re-use them as necessary, not allocate them within local groups.

Comment: I am not sure what this means. Are you suggesting that I do `\newcount` outside the group? Wouldn't I then have to do something like `\mycount 0\relax` within the group?

Comment: @DanielE.Shub You should do `\newcount` outside of the document body altogether, you should never dynamically use `\new...` macros in plain or latex they are just not designed for that. If your package needs three count registers it should have three `\newcount` commands you never need to do repeated allocations within a group, you just repeatedly assign values to the same register. Exactly yes you assign `\mycount0 ` or whatever other values you need, you don't re-allocate the `\mycount` register.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub well _never_ is too strong if you are defining a new allocation macro like `\newtheorem` then it makes sense for that to internally allocate a count, but then that command itself should only be used globally in the preamble.